# How to add GitHub pull request as development link in Azure DevOps [Stake Holder]

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am assigned in a Azure DevOps project as a Stake Holder and I want to add a pull request url to the tak assigned to me. I am a collaborator for that project in GitHub and the repo is private. When I add the url I am getting the following error **The 'PullRequest' url cannot be resolved. Please check the url and try again.**

[image: StakeHolder pull request]

When I enter the same url as a Basic User there is no error.

[image: Basic User pull request]

Is there some prerequisite for adding the GitHub pull request or GitHub commit url if you are a StakeHolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some prerequisite for adding the GitHub pull request or GitHub commit url if you are a StakeHolder

According to the document [Link GitHub commits, pull requests, and issues to work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/link-to-from-github?view=azure-devops):

Prerequisites:

- **Your Azure Boards project must be connected to the GitHub repository**
- You must be a **Contributor** to Azure Boards.
- You must be a **Contributor** to the GitHub repository.

So, to resolve this issue, please check if you are have the Contributor for your project when you assigned in a Azure DevOps project as a Stake Holder:

[image]

Then check if you have **connect to the correct GitHub repository** when you use **Stake Holder** account.

Hope this helps.